# git checkout to temp work tree without altering index

Tags: git

I'm creating a git `post-checkout` hook to ensure my database state is consistent as I move between branches, but I'm running into a peculiar problem.

To make this work, I have to access migrations from both the "from" branch and from the "to" branch. The `post-checkout` hook runs after the index and work tree have been brought up to date with the "to" branch. What it does is this:

1. Runs `GIT_WORK_TREE=/tmp/from-branch git checkout $from_branch -- db` to get the db files of the "from" branch into `/tmp/from-branch/db`.
2. Runs `GIT_WORK_TREE=/tmp/to-branch git checkout $to_branch -- db` to get the db files of the "to" branch into `/tmp/to-branch`.
3. Finds the common ancestor among the migrations.
4. Runs the necessary downward migrations from `/tmp/from-branch`.
5. Runs any new upward migrations from the current working tree in the repo.

This all works splendidly, except that after it runs, git is showing the following:

```
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        new file:   db/migrations/non-prod/20180718_102122-new-one-test-data.sql
        new file:   db/migrations/schema/20180718_102108-new-one.sql

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        deleted:    db/migrations/non-prod/20180718_102122-new-one-test-data.sql
        deleted:    db/migrations/schema/20180718_102108-new-one.sql
```

These two files are the files that were checked out from `$from_branch` into the tmp work tree. Git seems to be assuming that I'm checking them into my repo (despite my setting the `GIT_WORK_TREE` variable to another path) and automatically adding them to the index as "staged". I've combed the `git-checkout` manpage for options that would prevent this and haven't found any.

My current best solution is to run `git reset` after the checkout, but that feels like a hack. Just wondering if anyone else can think of some better solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your terminology is a little bit off, but this is essentially correct: `git checkout` copies files into the index first, before copying them out to the work-tree.  This is how it is that the index indexes or caches the work-tree—hence the names *the index* and *the cache*.  (Git also uses the index's cached information to minimize the amount of actual work done, so that if the files already exist in the work-tree in the correct form, Git does not have to touch them there.)

You are, as you note, using a *different*, temporarily overridden, work-tree.  What you need, then, is a different, temporarily overridden, index.  And in fact, Git supports just that:

```
TF=$(mktemp)
trap "rm -f $TF" 0 1 2 3 15   # clean up on exit

rm -f $TF # Git prefers a non-existent file to an empty one
GIT_INDEX_FILE=$TF GIT_WORK_TREE=/tmp/from-branch git checkout $from_branch -- db
rm -f $TF
GIT_INDEX_FILE=$TF GIT_WORK_TREE=/tmp/to-branch git checkout $to_branch -- db
... proceed as before
```

Note that rather than removing the temporary index each time, you could, if you choose to keep the `/tmp/from-branch` and `/tmp/to-branch` work-trees around as *permanent* work-trees, use two *permanent* indexes to index those two work-trees.